# How to create directory based subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

Suppose I have a domain as `abc.com`, which is inside `/htdocs/` directory. Now I am adding a blog to that as `/htdocs/blog/`.

Now I want this blog to browse like as `blog.abc.com` instead of `abc.com/blog`. But I don't want to do it for all the directory. How to do it using `.htaccess` or some PHP code?

Here I want to create sub domain only for this blog, not for other directory present inside `/htdocs/`, which is the correct way to do it? & what are the possible way to do it.

Comment: While browsing i got that i need "Apache webserver that accepts wildcard(*) domain names". how to configure Apache for this support. coz i have a domain hosted in amazon cloud.

Comment: Is it possible using php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the sub-domain `blog.abc.com` then use the following .htaccess code to turn abc.com/blog into blog.abc.com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.abc.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

Finally, go to blog.abc.com.